# how to get forecast error measures in R after outliers detection using tsoutliers

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, outliers

I used the `tsoutliers` package in R for outlier detection. Thereafter I used the following code to obtain a forecast:

```
x <- ts(x, frequency=12, start=c(2006,1))
res <- tso(x, types=c("AO","LS","TC"))

# define the variables containing the outliers for
# the observations outside the sample   
npred <- 12 # number of periods ahead to forecast 
newxreg <- outliers.effects(res$outliers, length(x) + npred)
newxreg <- ts(newxreg[-seq_along(x),], start = c(2012, 1))

# obtain the forecasts
p <- predict(res$fit, n.ahead=npred, newxreg=newxreg)
```

My question is, how do I obtain forecast measures such as ME, RMSE, MAE, MPE, MASE after using the predict function to obtain forecast as above?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is primarily about software implementation.  It also is unclear because it does not explain how outliers were removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the measures of accuracy this way:

1)  Retain your model:

```
model_out <- forecast::auto.arima(x=x, xreg = res$fit$xreg, ic = "bic")
```

2) Obtain the forecasts using the forecast function:

```
p <- forecast.Arima(model_out, h =12, xreg= newxreg )
```

3) ask for the accuracy measures.

```
accuracy(p)
```

Hope this help.